# Bootstrap ¿Cómo Poner labels a los costados en form?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Usando Bootstrap estoy tratando de poner los labels de un form en los costados y se deforma todo el form.

[image: Así se ve ahora]

Quisiera que por ej: el label "Nombre:" esté a la izquierda del input "nombre".

Pero si uso la clase "form-inline" pasa esto:
[image: form deforme]

De qué manera podría lograr poner los labels a la izquierda sin tener este resultado?

Mi código html se ve así:

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Editar Cuenta</h1>
<hr>
<form role="form">
    <div class="well">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" tabindex="1">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="apellido">Apellido:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido" tabindex="2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" tabindex="4">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="celular">Celular:</label>
                    <input type="number" name="celular" id="celular" class="form-control" placeholder="Celular" tabindex="3">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dni">Número de D.N.I.:</label>
            <input type="number" name="dni" id="dni" class="form-control" placeholder="Número de D.N.I." tabindex="5" disabled>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="contraseña">Contraseña actual:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña actual" tabindex="6">
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Contraseña nueva:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña nueva" tabindex="6">
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Confirmar contraseña nueva:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirmar contraseña nueva" tabindex="7">
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"><input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-lg" tabindex="7"
                title="Guardar datos ingresados"></div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"><input type="submit" value="Cancelar" class="btn btn-block btn-lg" tabindex="8">
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregarnos el código que tienes actualmente? Ahora mismo es muy difícil adivinar la estructura de HTML/CSS que tienes en tu código.

Comment: Agregué mi código html.

Comment: A tu `form` le hace falta la clase `form-inline` o `form-horizontal`, dependiendo cual vayas a utilizar

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer eso con bootstrap necesitas añadir algunas cosas a tu código, primero al div form group tienes que añadirle row para convertirlo a una fila, luego a tu label tienes que añadrile las clases col-form-label y col-x-x, la primera para que se alinee verticalmente con el input al que acompaña y la segunda para indicar cuantas columas ocupará, en este ejemplo he puesto col-sm-4, y por último el input tienes que encerrarlo en un div y a ese div darle la clase col-x-x para indicarle las columnas que ocupará, en este ejemplo he puesto col-sm-8, aquí tienes un label y un input individuales con lo que te he dicho añadido para que lo veas individualmente:

```
<div class="form-group row">
                <label for="nombre" class="col-form-label col-sm-4">Nombre:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" tabindex="1">
              </div>
            </div>
```

Y este es tu ejemplo añadiendo lo indicado:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
<h1>Editar Cuenta</h1>
<hr>
<form role="form">
    <div class="well">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="nombre" class="col-form-label col-sm-4">Nombre:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" tabindex="1">
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="apellido" class="col-form-label col-sm-4">Apellido:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido" tabindex="2">
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="email" class="col-form-label col-sm-4">Email:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" tabindex="4">
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="celular" class="col-form-label col-sm-4">Celular:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="number" name="celular" id="celular" class="form-control" placeholder="Celular" tabindex="3">
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="dni" class="col-form-label col-sm-4">Número de D.N.I.:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="number" name="dni" id="dni" class="form-control" placeholder="Número de D.N.I." tabindex="5" disabled>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="contraseña" class="col-form-label col-sm-4">Contraseña actual:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña actual" tabindex="6">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="password" class="col-form-label col-sm-4">Contraseña nueva:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña nueva" tabindex="6">
                  </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="password" class="col-form-label col-sm-4">Confirmar contraseña nueva:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirmar contraseña nueva" tabindex="7">
                  </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"><input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-lg" tabindex="7"
                title="Guardar datos ingresados"></div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"><input type="submit" value="Cancelar" class="btn btn-block btn-lg" tabindex="8">
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap cuenta con una propiedad que es `form-inline`

```
<form action="" class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
          <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
    </div>
</form>
```

De esta forma el `label` estara en linea junto con tu input.
Otra alternativa tambien seria el `form-horizontal`

```
<form action="" class="form-horizontal">
       <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-sm-2" for="nombre">Nombre</label>
               <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
              </div>
       </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Precisamente el OP es lo que dice, que está utilizando la propiedad `form-inline` y muestra un ejemplo de como le queda en su proyecto. Hasta que no veamos un ejemplo de como tiene su HTML no podremos ayudarle.

Answer (score 0):

Has probado de esta forma? (definiendoles un tamaño fijo a ambos)

```
<form method="" action="" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2"> Nombre </label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" id="nombre" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <label class="col-md-2"> Apellido </label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" id="apellido" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Aún así, queda un poco deforme.

Comment: Podrías pasar una captura de como queda? Porque así como te dije en mi caso queda así*... Quizás con un poquito de CSS extra ya podamos solucionar el tema... 
*: https://imgur.com/a/Bm55E

Comment: Sí, disculpa. Así es como queda *https://i.imgur.com/IGJyopB.jpg

Comment: No sé por qué el nombre queda con ese espacio y los demás campos no.